# Why is it giving me error of "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead"

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

[image: Output as shown and thrown error]I used regressor.fit([X_train], [Y_train]), it did worked but when I ran the below code ,it gave me the following error "ValueError: shapes (1,9) and (21,21) not aligned: 9 (dim 1) != 21 (dim 0)"

Please help

Comment: The error is pretty clear in my opinion.. You are having incorrect dims, Why don't you take a look at the docs and see what's expected dims?

Comment: Does it work after X_train_reshaped = X_train.reshape(21,1) and use of X_train_reshaped in the fit? Your X for training needs shape (21,1) instead of (21,).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the index chosen and the dimension. Change x to

`X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values`